# After starting startActivity driver is still in previous package

Tags: appium

```
        Activity activity = new Activity("com.android.chrome","com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
        activity.setStopApp(false);((StartsActivity)driver).startActivity(activity); 
    Thread.sleep(5000); 
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GJTzPOIoqs");
```

Driver not switching to current activity. It is in previous Apppackage only

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the activity name? Could be that **com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main** is not the activity which starts the app.

You could try to re-initialize the driver and set the browser in the capabilities:

```
public static AndroidDriver<?> setUpForChrome(){
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.2.2");
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android");
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
  ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
  options.setExperimentalOption("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome");
  capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

  return (AndroidDriver<?>) new RemoteWebDriver(appiumUrl, capabilities);
}
```

Maybe you need to stop your other app first with driver.closeApp() like:

```
driver.closeApp();
driver = setUpForChrome();
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GJTzPOIoqs");
```